# TDD - How would a concrete implementation be provided the concrete version of factory logic?

Tags: c#, tdd, solid-principles

For the example, we have a ShipmentInformationModelFactory, it's purpose is to populate a model and return it.

```
internal class ShipmentInformationModelFactory
{
    private IGetCarrierServiceFactory getCarrierServiceFactory;

    public ShipmentInformationModelFactory(IGetCarrierServiceFactory getCarrierServiceFactory)
    {
        this.getCarrierServiceFactory = getCarrierServiceFactory;
    }


    internal ShipmentInformation Create(ICarrierTransaction carrierTransaction, CarrierPackage carrierPackage)
    {
        ShipmentInformation shipmentInformation = new ShipmentInformation();

        // Get the Carrier Service Model for the ID of the carrier service against the Package.
        ICarrierServiceModel carrierServiceModel = this.getCarrierServiceFactory.Get(carrierPackage.CarrierServiceId);

        shipmentInformation.ServiceCode = carrierServiceModel.Code;

        return shipmentInformation;
    }
}
```

We then have a MockGetCarrierServiceFactory which just returns some stub data.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateShipmentInformation_ShipmentData()
    {
        ShipmentInformationModelFactory shipmentInformationModelFactory = new ShipmentInformationModelFactory(new MockGetCarrierServiceFactory());

        ShipmentInformation shipmentInformation = shipmentInformationModelFactory.Create();
    }

    internal class MockGetCarrierServiceFactory : IGetCarrierServiceFactory
    {
        public ICarrierServiceModel Get(int carrierServiceModelID)
        {
            ICarrierServiceModel carrierServiceModel = Mock.Create<ICarrierServiceModel>();

            Mock.Arrange(() => carrierServiceModel.Code).Returns("TestCarrier");

            Mock.Arrange(() => carrierServiceModel.Description).Returns("TestDescription");

            return carrierServiceModel;
        }
    }
```

This works wonderful and I feel like it follows SOLID principles quite well, please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

My problem comes with the (live) concrete version of this implementation. At which point should the concrete version of GetCarrierServiceFactory be passed into ShipmentInformationModelFactory?

Should I do down the route of creating a default constructor and having it auto populated inside there?

The class which instantiates the ShipmentInformationModelFactory object could pass provided it into the constructor but I've just created a dependency there.

I feel like I'm understanding TDD and SOLID principles 80% but am getting lost when it comes to the creation of these factories.

Answer (score 2):

> The class which instantiates the ShipmentInformationModelFactory object could pass provided it into the constructor but I've just created a dependency there.

You have to have dependencies. `ShipmentInformationModelFactory` is dependent on a concrete implementation of `IGetCarrierServiceFactory`. The key is to avoid those dependencies becoming couplings.

If you go for the default constructor route, then you hard code that dependency within `ShipmentInformationModelFactory`, thus tightly coupling the two.

So the solution is to provide that dependency at application start-up. From the start point of your code, either use an IoC container to fulfil those dependencies, or use pure DI (ie, write your own mapping code).

That way, the two classes remain loosely coupled and your testing approach still works, but you can also wire up the real dependencies in the application itself.

Comment: Interesting, I'd never heard of IoC containers before. Whats the most common way of resolving this issue, is it via IoC?